# Using JS how to load 2nd ad image right after 1st ad image is loaded

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cookies, promise

I am trying to figure out how to make the 2nd ad image to load ONLY RIGHT AFTER 1st ad image is loaded (see image with blue boxes). The reason is I have a CSS animation coming from 1st ad image and then going to the 2nd ad image in a smooth transition without interruption. If 1st ad image doesn't load properly, both won't sync.

I researched it and there are a few ways to do it. I could use cookie to store 1st ad image and then load 2nd ad image or use Promise or async function. Not sure where to go from here.

[image: Website with ads]

Thanks.

Comment: images dispatch `load` events when they've .... loaded - no idea why you'd use a cookie to store an image though - you also mention `CSS animation` so if it's not an infinite animation, you can also listen for an `animationend` event to know when an animation ends

Answer (score 1):

There are a few SO posts ([`async/await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854355/wait-for-image-loading-to-complete-in-javascript/56341485#56341485) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded)) that list solutions to loading images using JavaScript and then executing callbacks once loaded.

Here's a modified version of the `async/await` function from the first link. (Main modification: I do not build a separate images array but instead pass the `img` object/element in the resolved promise for a loaded image.)

```
async function loadImages(urlArr) {
    // Create an array for promises
    const promiseArr = [];

    // Iterate the array of URLs passed into the 'loadImages()'
    // function and build a list of promises.
    urlArr.forEach(url => {
        promiseArr.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const img = new Image();
            // Resolve the promise when the image has been loaded.
            // Pass the 'img' element as a parameter in the
            // 'resolve()' function. This builds an array of
            // 'img' elements returned by 'Promise.all()'. 
            img.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(img));
            img.addEventListener("error", () => reject(img));
            img.src = url;
        }));
    });

    // Wait for all images to be loaded
    // and then return an array of 'img' elements.
    return await Promise.all(promiseArr);
}
```

Once all images are loaded, iterate the array of `img` elements returned by `Promise.all()` in the last line of the function above.

Note that an image that cannot be found (i.e. a 404 error) results in a resolved promise as opposed to a rejected promise. The image size, however, will be 0 or 1. Assuming you aren't loading a 1x1 sized image, the following filter works to determine `img` elements that have 404 (Not Found) responses.

```
const failedImages = images.filter(img => img.width <= 1);

if (failedImages.length > 0) {
    failedImages.forEach(img => {
        console.log(`The image ${img.src} failed to load.`);
    });
    return;
}
```

If all images are loaded successfully, then use a `transitionend` listener (or `animationend` listener as noted in @JaromandaX's comment) to trigger the display of the second ad image.

```
const transitionendListener = () => {
    // Trigger transition animation for the sidebar ad
    sidebarAdEl.classList.add("show");
    bannerAdEl.removeEventListener("transitionend", transitionendListener);
};

bannerAdEl.addEventListener("transitionend", transitionendListener);

// Adding the 'show' class name triggers a 'transform'
// transition set up in the '.ad.show .img-container'
// CSS style rule.
bannerAdEl.classList.add("show");
```

Putting the above together in a working sample:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialize);

function initialize() {
    const urlList = [
        "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png",
        "https://www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png"
    ];

    loadImages(urlList).then(images => {

        // An image that cannot be found (i.e. a 404 error)
        // still results in a resolved promise. The image
        // size, however, will be 0 or 1.
        const failedImages = images.filter(img => img.width <= 1);

        if (failedImages.length > 0) {
            failedImages.forEach(img => {
                console.log(`The image ${img.src} failed to load.`);
            });
            return;
        }

        showImages(images);
    });
}

// Async/await 'loadImages()' function adapted from:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854355/wait-for-image-loading-to-complete-in-javascript/56341485#56341485
// See additional answers posted here:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded
async function loadImages(urlArr) {
    // Create an array for promises
    const promiseArr = [];

    // Iterate the array of URLs passed into the 'loadImages()'
    // function and build a list of promises.
    urlArr.forEach(url => {
        promiseArr.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const img = new Image();
            // Resolve the promise when the image has been loaded.
            // Pass the 'img' element as a parameter in the
            // 'resolve()' function. This builds an array of
            // 'img' elements returned by 'Promise.all()'. 
            img.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(img));
            img.addEventListener("error", () => reject(img));
            img.src = url;
        }));
    });

    // Wait for all images to be loaded
    // and then return an array of 'img' elements.
    return await Promise.all(promiseArr);
}

function showImages(images) {
    const bannerAdEl = document.querySelector(".ad.banner");
    const sidebarAdEl = document.querySelector(".ad.sidebar");

    bannerAdEl.querySelector(".img-container").appendChild(images[0]);
    sidebarAdEl.querySelector(".img-container").appendChild(images[1]);

    const transitionendListener = () => {
        // Trigger transition animation for the sidebar ad
        sidebarAdEl.classList.add("show");
        bannerAdEl.removeEventListener("transitionend", transitionendListener);
    };

    bannerAdEl.addEventListener("transitionend", transitionendListener);

    // Adding the 'show' class name triggers a 'transform'
    // transition set up in the '.ad.show .img-container'
    // CSS style rule.
    bannerAdEl.classList.add("show");
}
```

```css
/* ----------------------------------------------------
    Layout
*/

.layout {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        'banner-ad banner-ad banner-ad'
        'sidebar-left main-content sidebar-ad'
        'sidebar-left main-content sidebar-right';
    grid-template-rows: 6rem 10rem auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}


.ad.banner {
    grid-area: banner-ad;
}

.ad.sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar-ad;
}

.sidebar-left {
    grid-area: sidebar-left;
}

.main-content {
    grid-area: main-content;
}

.sidebar-right {
    grid-area: sidebar-right;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------
    Style
*/

.ad {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.sidebar-left,
.main-content,
.sidebar-right {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.sidebar-right {
    min-height: 20rem;
}

.layout-label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem;
}


/* ----------------------------------------------------
    Image
*/

.ad img {
    /* Center image element within its parent */
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /* Fit the image element within its parent */
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.ad {
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .ad .img-container {
        display: grid;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition: transform 1s;
    }

    .ad.show .img-container {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
```

```html
<div class="layout">
    <div class="ad banner"><div class="img-container"></div></div>
    <div class="ad sidebar"><div class="img-container"></div></div>
    <div class="sidebar-left">
        <span class="layout-label">Sidebar Left</span>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        <span class="layout-label">Main Content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-right">
        <span class="layout-label">Sidebar Right</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: If the images do not transition in the first time 'Run code snippet' button is clicked above, then click the button again with the results window already expanded.

**Loading `iframe` elements into banner and sidebar ad containers**

(Jan 23, 2024 edit)

I've modified my original answer to load `iframe` elements instead of `img` elements. I preserved the main structure of the original solution. I used inline frame sources from the [MDN article on `iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialize);

function initialize() {
  // URL sources taken from examples at:
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe
  const urlList = [
    "https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-0.004017949104309083%2C51.47612752641776%2C0.00030577182769775396%2C51.478569861898606&layer=mapnik",
    "https://example.org"
  ];

  loadInlineFrames(urlList).then(iframes => {

    // TO DO: Check for content load failure in 'iframe' elements.
    const faileInlineFrames = [];

    // An 'iframe' source that cannot be found (i.e. a 404 error)
    // still results in a resolved promise.

    // "If the iframe and the iframe's parent document are Same Origin,
    // returns a Document(that is, the active document in the
    // inline frame's nested browsing context), else returns null."
    // Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument

    // Check for the existence of an image tag after verifying the
    // 'contentDocument' property is valid object (see note above). 
    // If an image tag cannot be found, then an error occurred.
    //const faileInlineFrames = iframes.filter(iframe => iframe.contentDocument && iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML.indexOf("<img") === -1);

    if (faileInlineFrames.length > 0) {
      faileInlineFrames.forEach(iframe => {
        console.log(`The iframe ${iframe.src} failed to load.`);
      });
      return;
    }

    showInlineFrames(iframes);
  });
}

// Async/await 'loadInlineFrames()' function adapted from:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854355/wait-for-image-loading-to-complete-in-javascript/56341485#56341485
// See additional answers posted here:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded
async function loadInlineFrames(urlArr) {
  // Create an array for promises
  const promiseArr = [];

  // Iterate the array of URLs passed into the 'loadInlineFrames()'
  // function and build a list of promises.
  urlArr.forEach(url => {
    promiseArr.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const iframeEl = document.createElement("iframe");
      // Resolve the promise when the 'iframe' has been loaded.
      // Pass the 'iframe' element as a parameter in the
      // 'resolve()' function. This builds an array of
      // 'iframe' elements returned by 'Promise.all()'.
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#error_and_load_event_behavior
      iframeEl.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(iframeEl));
      iframeEl.addEventListener("error", () => reject(iframeEl));
      iframeEl.setAttribute("src", url);
      iframeEl.style.display = "none";
      // "Setting the src of a newly created iframe in javascript
      // does not trigger the HTML parser until the element is
      // inserted into the document."
      // Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10419102
      document.body.appendChild(iframeEl);
    }));
  });

  // Wait for all iframes to be loaded
  // and then return an array of 'img' elements.
  return await Promise.all(promiseArr);
}

function showInlineFrames(iframes) {
  const bannerAdEl = document.querySelector(".ad.banner");
  const sidebarAdEl = document.querySelector(".ad.sidebar");

  iframes[0].style.display = "block";
  iframes[1].style.display = "block";

  bannerAdEl.querySelector(".iframe-container").appendChild(iframes[0]);
  sidebarAdEl.querySelector(".iframe-container").appendChild(iframes[1]);

  const transitionendListener = () => {
    // Trigger transition animation for the sidebar ad
    sidebarAdEl.classList.add("show");
    bannerAdEl.removeEventListener("transitionend", transitionendListener);
  };

  bannerAdEl.addEventListener("transitionend", transitionendListener);

  // Adding the 'show' class name triggers a 'transform'
  // transition set up in the '.ad.show .iframe-container'
  // CSS style rule.
  bannerAdEl.classList.add("show");
}
```

```css
/* ----------------------------------------------------
    Layout
*/

.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'banner-ad banner-ad banner-ad' 'sidebar-left main-content sidebar-ad' 'sidebar-left main-content sidebar-right';
  grid-template-rows: 6rem 10rem auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.ad.banner {
  grid-area: banner-ad;
}

.ad.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar-ad;
}

.sidebar-left {
  grid-area: sidebar-left;
}

.main-content {
  grid-area: main-content;
}

.sidebar-right {
  grid-area: sidebar-right;
}


/* ----------------------------------------------------
    Style
*/

.ad {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.sidebar-left,
.main-content,
.sidebar-right {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.sidebar-right {
  min-height: 20rem;
}

.layout-label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem;
}


/* ----------------------------------------------------
    Image
*/

.ad img {
  /* Center image element within its parent */
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* Fit the image element within its parent */
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.ad {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ad .iframe-container {
  display: grid;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.ad .iframe-container iframe {
  width: 100%;
}

.ad.show .iframe-container {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="ad banner">
    <div class="iframe-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ad sidebar">
    <div class="iframe-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-left">
    <span class="layout-label">Sidebar Left</span>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <span class="layout-label">Main Content</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-right">
    <span class="layout-label">Sidebar Right</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work in a same page but it looks like it won't work if 2 images are in separate iframe. 1st image is in the banner iframe and 2nd image is in the sidebar iframe. How would I do this? I separated sidebar into different template and doesn't catch it.

Comment: I added a second sample that loads `iframe` elements into the banner and sidebar ad elements.